# Change target audience during the authorization of my app to "Only Me"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

In my app when it asks permission to post on someone's wall there is a drop down where you can set the audience for the posts. For example there are "Public", "Friends", "Only me" and "Custom". Right now the default is "Friends" I would like to change the default to "Only Me".
I feel like it has to maybe go in the scope? Here is my login call:

```
FB.login(function (response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    //do stuff
                } else {
                    // The person cancelled the login dialog - do nothing to the UI.                
                }
            }, { scope: 'publish_stream' });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found you can set this in the app settings. 
Go to:
developers.facebook.com 
Select: App Details
click button: Configure App Center Permissions
and you can select the audience in the "Default Activity Privacy" drop down